# Java changing multiple panel

Tags: java

i want to create a gui that allow me to change through differents frame, i have a main frame where there are multiple button and when clicking on the button i want to open a new page (like a "display PDF" button), when closing the page created by the button i wantto go back to main frame.

I made a code with creation of differnet Jframe and it works as i want, but i would like to know if there is a bettere and simpler why to do this.

```
public class MultiplePanelsExample {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton[] buttons;

public MultiplePanelsExample() {
    // Step 1: Create the main frame and panel
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Panel");
    mainPanel = new JPanel();

    // Step 2: Create an array of buttons
    buttons = new JButton[3]; // Adjust the number based on how many buttons you need

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton("Open Panel " + (i + 1));
        mainPanel.add(buttons[i]);
    }

    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    // Step 3: Add action listeners to the buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        final int buttonIndex = i;
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openSecondaryPanel(buttonIndex);
                mainFrame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }


}

private void openSecondaryPanel(int buttonIndex) {
    // Step 4: Create the secondary frame and panel
    JFrame secondaryFrame = new JFrame("Panel " + (buttonIndex + 1));
    JPanel secondaryPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea tx = new JTextArea("Name ");

    secondaryPanel.add(tx);
    secondaryFrame.add(secondaryPanel);
    secondaryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    secondaryFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {


                // NOW we change it to dispose on close..
                secondaryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                secondaryFrame.setVisible(false);
                secondaryFrame.dispose();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    secondaryFrame.setVisible(true);





    secondaryFrame.pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MultiplePanelsExample();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

### Strong dependency

each frame must know about the other, they are strong dependent on each other. Instead of using a class that solves this (strong) dependency (in your case: `MultiplePanelsExample`) you should try to create independent components.

**Idea (pseudo code) of using independent classes:**

```
public MyComponent {

private final Component successor;

public MyComponent(Component successor){
    this.successor = successor;
}

...

public void onClose(){
    successor.setVisible(true)
}
```

this approach would let you build independent components and you are open to adjust your workflow more easily. Additionally it increases testability since you can test each component now on its own.

### side notes

- declare an interface `SuccessorComponent` that can be injected to your components! doing this will further increase testability since you can now very easy mock/simulate your successor.
- having such an architektur you can easily create new/different workflow: **A-->B-->C-->A** for example
- the example code above is not really working it should only provide an idea of how independet components would look like